Load specific layer of GeoServer to A WMSLayer using Esri JSAPI 4
I am trying to load a geoserver wms layer to a WMSLayer using Esri JS API 4.x, thought the code below loads ok using Esri JS API 3.x
require(["esri/layers/WMSLayer","esri/layers/WMSLayerInfo"],function(WMSLayer,WMSLayerInfo){
    var wmsinfo = new WMSLayerInfo();

    var resourceInfo = {
        extent: Map.extent,
        layerInfos: [wmsinfo],
        spatialReference: {
          wkid: 4326
        }
    };
    var name = "HTM:name_of_layer_on_geoserver.tif";
    var url = "www.geoserver.local:8080/geoserver/HTM/wms?";
    layer = new WMSLayer(url, {
        id: "tempid",
        
        spatialReference: new SpatialReference({ wkid: 3857 }),
        resourceInfo: resourceInfo,
        visibleLayers: name,
        customLayerParameters: {CRS: 'EPSG:3857'}
    });

    Map.addLayer(layer);
});

now im trying to convert it.
require(["esri/layers/WMSLayer"],function(WMSLayer){
    //var wmsinfo = new WMSLayerInfo(); //<-this is deprecated, what would be the equivalent.

    var resourceInfo = {
        extent: View.extent,
        layerInfos: [],
        spatialReference: {
          wkid: 4326
        }
    };
    var name = "HTM:name_of_layer_on_geoserver.tif";
    var url = "www.geoserver.local:8080/geoserver/HTM/wms?";
    //moved url to properties, instead of inline argument 
    layer = new WMSLayer({
        id: "tempid",
        url:url,
        spatialReference: new SpatialReference({ wkid: 3857 }),
        resourceInfo: resourceInfo, //this doesnt seem to be available
        visibleLayers: name,   
        customLayerParameters: {CRS: 'EPSG:3857'}
    });
        layer.load().then(()=>{
      Map.addLayer(layer);
        });
});

i tried replacing visiblelayer property with sublayer but doesnt seem to work.
if i just add it to Map without the load(), it will be white screen, if i do call load(), it will stuck in getcapabilities request. i where lost that a specific class doesnt have equivalent or samples that will load a single layer rather than the all layers available in the server.
what am i missing?

The sublayers property indicates the collection of layers to be displayed, objects of class WMSSubLayer (ArcGIS JS API - WMSSublayer). That is the class you are looking for, the one that "replace" WMSLayerInfo of api 3.
Once you load, you can play with the layers of the resource and their properties. There are a couple of examples both in the specification of WMSSubLayer (link above), and on WMSLayer (ArcGIS JS API- WMSLayer sublayers)
